# Timebase effect on measuring ripple on SMPS

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, frequency, ripple

hey everyone i get straight to  the point, look at these two pics below are we losing anything in the peak-peak measurement when using 5us instead of 5ms?(they are two different units)
if yes by mow much?

[image]

(5ms)

[image]

(5us)

does using lower timebase "hide" any specific frequency?(some one told me the 5us one hide`s mains 50-60hz ripple effect on the output therefore the pk-pk value is smaller on 5us one than what it should be)
note:
probes was connected directly to the load tester on both test and the main ac input is  ~2200v@50hz.....+ scope bandwidth was set at 20mhz on both tests..
my main question  is that how much these two measurement are comparable...

Comment: yep, the oscillation in the 5ms timebase is 50Hz mains noise with superposed switching noise (and God only knows what else). At the 5 us timebase, the 50Hz oscillation is basically flat, so you can no longer see it. You are left with a roughly 100 kHz switching noise. Still superposed to a 50 Hz sine, buy you won't see that since you are triggering at a handful of mV (and in the 50 us of the window the mains signal won't change appreciably).

Comment: You should spend some time playing around with both the timebase and trigger level controls on your scope, just to see all of the different ways that you can view such a complex waveform. The scope won't lie to you, but you do need to be sure you're asking the right question!

Comment: so the reported pk-pk values on 5us are indeed lower than what it would be if we were to use 5ms (my main thing was taht time base effects what is being shown in the display but does it effect the reported pk-pk too?)
so if we do tests again using 2ms time base both of our pk-kp values would be greater?

note:the thing is i dont have access to a loadtest unit so its not really possible to do the test again...

Comment: It seems to me you are implying that those two oscillations are the same signal. They are not. The 50Hz one is the ghost of mains voltage - it could be 5mVpp or 20mVpp or even 12Vpp. This amplitude has more to do with capacitive coupling of your probe with the mains lines - if you grab the probe cable and put your foot near a mains plug, you will see this rise, and rise... It has nothing to do with SMPS switching noise. The signal at the bottom is the SMPS switching noise, and its amplitude depends on your SMPS brick. Different things, they just happen to look alike. If I got you wrong, sorry

Comment: If you need to further clarify your question, I suggest you crop the pictures to the screen only of your scope (so that you can have it a 100% magnification) and draw a few lines to show what is the amplitude you are referring to in the first picture.

Comment: @sredni-vashtar let me be clear what we are trying to do:
we want to measure our smps  ripple at the dc output ...

in one of the measurements scope`s timebase happens to be at 5us because of that as you confirmed above we are suppressing our mains 50hz effect on the pk-pk value reported so my question now is can we "fix" that pk-pk value ? can we consider the "50hz ghost" a constant measurable on the power outlet and then average that with the result ?
if it seems to out of place(or doesn't make sense) my bad i`m still new to this stuff... 
tnx for the time btw...

Comment: Neither answer may be the correct one.  The 50us timebase is too fast  to see the 100 or 120 Hz ripple from the mains so will usually give a lower pk to pk reading.  The 5ms timebase will show the low frequency effects but may miss high frequency   peaks because of limited memory for sampling

Comment: @WarrenHill so 5ms is the more accurate one whats the max time base that makes sense to measure ?
can we measure main effect separately and sorta"add" it to the pk-pk value?

Answer (score 2):

When looking at power supply ripple it's very important to use good probing technique.  Long ground leads will lead to noise pickup and will give you poor results.

Once you have good probing technique you typically use a 20MHz BW limit on the scope, and set the timebase to view the high frequency ripple.

I usually capture a picture of what the ripple looks like, THEN set the scope for "infinite persistence" which will allow you to get a peak to peak value for the total ripple envelope, e.g. if there is low frequency ripple from poor mains rejection.